# Server Client communication Java to Swift

Tags: java, android, ios

This is my first time asking so excuse my stupidity.

I am writing an App currently, It's on Android and IOS as well. The clients all communicate to a server I coded in Java. Communication with the android has been simple enough and I've already got that side finished.

Now that I have come to IOS side I have run into a problem.

I am using PrintWriter to write to OutputStream on the Server. On the IOS client side, I am using this code to communicate with the server
`

```
import Foundation
class Connection: NSObject, StreamDelegate {
    let host = ""
    let port = 1111
    var inputStream: InputStream?
    var outputStream: OutputStream?
    var name = ""
    var messageReceived = ""


    func connect() {

        Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: self.host, port: self.port, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)

        if inputStream != nil && outputStream != nil {

            // Set delegate
            inputStream!.delegate = self
            outputStream!.delegate = self

            // Schedule
            inputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            outputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

            print("Start open()")

            // Open!
            inputStream!.open()
            outputStream!.open()
        }
    }

     func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
            switch eventCode {
                case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
                    print("input: ErrorOccurred:)")
                    break
                case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
                    print("input: OpenCompleted")
                    break
                case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:

                    if (getResponse(length: 4) == "new\r\n") {
                        print("yup")
                        messageReceived = getResponse(length: 1)
                        if (messageReceived == "yes\r\n") {
                            print("asd")
                        }else if (messageReceived == "nos\r\n") {
                            print("sqrwe")
                        }else {
                            print(messageReceived)
                        }
                    }
                    print("input: HasBytesAvailable")
                    break
                case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
                    print("output: ErrorOccurred:)")
                    break
                case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
                    if name == "" {
                        sendMessage(message: "super")
                        name = "super"
                    }
                    print("output: HasSpaceAvailable")
                    break

                // Here you can write() to `outputStream`

                default:
                    break
            }

    }

    func sendMessage(message: String) {

        let anotherString = message + "\r\n"
        let encodedDataArray = [UInt8](anotherString.utf8)
        outputStream?.write(encodedDataArray, maxLength: encodedDataArray.count)
    }

    func getResponse(length: Int)-> String {
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
        var bytes = inputStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: length)
        let data = NSMutableData(bytes: &buffer, length: bytes!)

        let read = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: length)
        bytes! += read
        data.append(&buffer, length: read)

        var str:NSString! = ""
        str = NSString(bytes: data.bytes, length: bytes!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        return str as String


    }

    func getRespond() -> Int {
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 1)
        var bytes = inputStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: 1)
        let data = NSMutableData(bytes: &buffer, length: bytes!)

        let read = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: 1)
        bytes! += read
        data.append(&buffer, length: read)

        var str:NSString! = ""
        str = NSString(bytes: data.bytes, length: bytes!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        if let i = Int(str as String) {
            return i;
        }

        return 0

    }
}
```

I implemented the getResponse function dependent on the length provided in the call and the getResponse to receive just an Integer value. I had to do this because whenever I try to read using a buffer of length 1024(for example) the IOS client will just hang and keep waiting for the server to either close the connection or send that many characters(1024).

I was wondering if there's a way to communicate between the server and client without having to provide the message length. 
I have already tried flushing the stream from the server side, apparently, it doesn't do what it's meant to do any more unless it's overridden. I even tried using BufferedOutputStream instead of PrintWriter to write bytes and then flushing. Still nothing.